# why is this query not working in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a query, it doesn't work in PHPMyAdmin, shows some Syntax Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 12

```
create table appntmnt(
 appointment_id bigint unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
 user_id bigint unsigned not null,
 br_id bigint unsigned,
 brandname text,
 brname text,
 strt_time bigint unsigned,
 end_time bigint unsigned, 
 is_cancelled boolean,
 is_confirmed boolean,
 app_ser text,
 index appntmnt_table_index(brand_id, user_id);
 foreign key foreign_key1(user_id) references user(user_id) on delete cascade,
 foreign key foreign_key2(branch_id) references branch(branch_id) on delete cascade
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `index appntmnt_table_index(brand_id, user_id);` remove the `;` and put `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
create table appntmnt(
 appointment_id bigint unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
 user_id bigint unsigned not null,
 br_id bigint unsigned,
 brandname text,
 brname text,
 strt_time bigint unsigned,
 end_time bigint unsigned, 
 is_cancelled boolean,
 is_confirmed boolean,
 app_ser text,
 index appntmnt_table_index(br_id, user_id),
 foreign key foreign_key1(user_id) references user(user_id) on delete cascade,
 foreign key foreign_key2(br_id) references branch(branch_id) on delete cascade
);
```

updated last three lines check it.

Answer (score 1):

replace semicolon with comma at the end of the line

```
 index appntmnt_table_index(brand_id, user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo - the semicolon in the index line breaks the statement.

```
index appntmnt_table_index(brand_id, user_id);
```

so this part is invalid:

```
foreign key foreign_key1(user_id) references user(user_id) on delete cascade,
foreign key foreign_key2(branch_id) references branch(branch_id) on delete cascade
```

);

Just remove the semicolon and add a comma.

Answer (score 0):

There semicolon in the `index appntmnt_table_index(brand_id, user_id);` statement.

Change from

```
index appntmnt_table_index(brand_id, user_id);
```

To

```
index appntmnt_table_index(brand_id, user_id),
```